# SimpleDateFormat and Save it in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime

I'm using this structure:

`
class FT02Activ01 : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var data1: TextView



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ft02_activ01)
    data1 = findViewById(R.id.data)

    loadData()


override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    data1.text = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val dateSetListener =
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            val myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
            data1.text = sdf.format(cal.time)

        }

    data1.setOnClickListener {
        DatePickerDialog(
            this, dateSetListener,
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        ).show()
    }
}






 private fun saveData() {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putString("data_KEY", data1.text.toString())
    editor.apply()
}

 private fun loadData(){
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val savedString = sharedPreferences.getString("STRING_KEY", null)

    data1.text = sharedPreferences.getString("data_KEY", null)
```

`

If I change data1 to 19/06/2023 and go foward and the comeback to this page, it will bring back 20/06/2023, not 19/06/2023

My expecting is when go and turn back to the screen i get 19/06/2023

Answer (score 0):

In

```
onStart() {
   ...
           //DATA

        if (data1.text.isEmpty()) {
            val currentDate =
                SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
            data1.text = currentDate
        }



        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        val dateSetListener =
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

                val myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
                val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
                data1.text = sdf.format(cal.time)

            }

        data1.setOnClickListener {
            DatePickerDialog(
                this, dateSetListener,
                cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            ).show()
        }
```

the if statement resolves

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't really see you saving data anywhere. You are not using the `saveData()` method at all.
2. Even if you are loading data from `sharedPreferences`, you are overriding the new data. Basically, the Android Activity lifecycle states that `onStart()` is gonna get called after `onCreate()`. (you load the date on the `onCreate() and then you set another date on the` onStart()` method)
3. The new date you set on the `onStart()` method is not the saved date, instead, it is the current date(`System.currentTimeMillis()`)

I would recommend you to read more about [Android Activity and Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and see some samples of the [sharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) usage.

On a side note, a personal advice when saving time objects, you can save the millis of a date and convert to date obj., since manipulating with dates using `String` introduces new headaches on conversions.

Comment: Yeah, the save Data() is in another part of the code that i didn't shared